# How to know the number is a double

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int, double

I coded something in Java that looks at what was imputed as string and then convert that string into a double or an int **IF** there is a decimal (period) found. In my code it always jumps out of the loop and prints "no numbers found". Why is that? What is wrong.

My code:

```
//check if its actually numbers
if(leftSide.matches("[0-9]+") && rightSide.matches("[0-9]+")){
    System.out.println("numbers found");

    if(leftSide.contains(".") || rightSide.contains(".")){
        System.out.println("convert to doubles");
    }else{
        System.out.println("convert to ints");
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("no numbers found");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do it with try/catch?

Comment: Try debugging your code? Also `String.matches` will evaluate the whole string.

Comment: Please read this help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How are `leftSide` and `rightSide` instantiated?

Comment: this portion of code:

    if(leftSide.matches("[0-9]+") && rightSide.matches("[0-9]+"))

is in contradiction with the following one:

    if(leftSide.contains(".") || rightSide.contains(".")){

Comment: What's wrong with `if(string.contains(".")){`

Comment: I'm still new to programming...I just wasn't sure how to go about using a try/catch

Comment: I've showed it below with try/catch and I've tried it out with a few strings and it worked!

Comment: What loop are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you @Andy. It worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if the `String` is a `Double`, an `Integer` or if it isn't, yes?

I would do this:

```
public class Demo{

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String str = "54.45k";

        double num;

        try {
            num = Double.parseDouble(str);
            if((num == Math.floor(num)) && !Double.isInfinite(num)) {
                System.out.println("String is an Integer!");
            }else {
                System.out.println("String is a Double!");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("String isn't an Integer or a Double!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried it out and it worked!

Comment: Yes...well, I want to check if a period is in the string...that will mean the user is working with decimal numbers. If so, do the math with the string converted to a double. If not, convert the string to an integer.